# How to install BOINC

Tags: boinc

This machine is normally a BOINC cruncher, I've downloaded the installer, boinc_7.4.42_x86_64-pc-linux-gnu.sh, it would appear I have downloaded it 4 times actually. How do I run it? I've tried to click or double click it, which opened another window, but did nothing else. All I want it to do right now, is crunch BOINC work units.

Comment: Please add the output of `ls -la boinc_7.4.42_x86_64-pc-linux-gnu.sh` to your question. I believe you are running into a permissions problem. If I'm right, this information will confirm that. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: How do I get the terminal screen up to run the ls?

Comment: You can open a terminal with CTRL-ALT-T

Answer (score 2):

First of all: To use boinc, I'd recommend installing it through the software repositories, not from a script. (Simply search for *boinc* in the Ubuntu Software Centre. You can get boinc manager there, too).

There are many advantages in using the software sources instead of downloaded scripts. It's more secure and you'll get automatic updates through the update manager, for instance.

I never used this script and don't know if it's meant to open any windows or just print to the console its run in. To run it and see what's printed, open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl+Alt+T</kbd> or search *Terminal* in the Dash). You'll need the path the script is located in. Let's say its `/home/fossaw/Downloads`. You'd type `/home/fossaw/Downloads/boinc_7.4.42_x86_64-pc-linux-gnu.sh` in the terminal and hit enter, which runs the script.

If something is printed to the terminal that sound like there is a permission problem, run `sudo /home/fossaw/Downloads/boinc_7.4.42_x86_64-pc-linux-gnu.sh`. It will ask you for your password and hence run the script with root privileges.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl + Alt + T</kbd>).

Type `sudo apt-get install boinc-client boinc-manager`

Press Y.

Let it install.

Now press the <kbd>Super</kbd> key. Search Boinc.

Source: http://www.overclock.net/t/1449225/guide-installing-boinc-on-ubuntu-from-the-terminal

Answer (score 0):

BOINC is in the Ubuntu repositories. Open the Software Centre, search for boinc, and select for installation.